# Fullscreen spinning background image

Tags: jquery, image, css, fullscreen, spinning

i've been looking everywhere how to achieve this effect of an animated spinning image that is covering the whole screen. [Like this one](http://demo.readymag.com/mag/1/).

bassically, what i want is to make it spin and to be fullscreen.

this is what i got so far, http://losmosca.com.ar/reiki/

HTML:

```
<img src="img/bg.jpg" id='test' class='rotating'>
```

CSS3:

```
#test {
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:1000px;
height:1000px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
     from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
     }
     to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
     }
}

.rotating {
    -webkit-animation: rotating 1000s linear infinite;
}
```

as you can see, i can make it spin but not fullscreen, is it possible?
thank you!

Comment: You have to make your image resolution higher. @user2207103

Comment: They're using javascript rather than CSS for animation. Using Transform and then the scale/rotate properties.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `width:100%;` rather than `width:1000px;`

and `height:100%` rather than `height:1000px;`

Cool effect by the way, I may have to find an excuse to use that trick.

Comment: i tried that, but when spinning you see the black body background.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I see what you're talking about in Chrome, 100% works in Firefox.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. When you figure it out be sure to post it.

Comment: the spinning works in chrome but not in firefox. changed it to 100% and it looks weird. i think i need to use jquery for this.